# How to disable mongosh logging?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-4.0

I'm using `mongosh` v1.1.7 and I'd like to disable logging ([these ones](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/logs/)) because it's taking up all my disk space.
How can I do that?

I found a similar [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/264772/how-to-disable-mongodb-shell-logs) but it only applies to `mongo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today it is not possible, but there is a [feature request](https://feedback.mongodb.com/forums/929233-mongodb-shell/suggestions/45821290-control-logging-behavior-of-mongosh).

In order to limit the logs, I created this cronjob which runs every hour.

```
/usr/bin/find ~/.mongodb/mongosh/ -mindepth 1 -mmin +60 -name "*_log" -delete
```

Comment: That's what I thought. My problem is caused by a long-running script that performs many queries and results in a single huge log file. So the cronjob solution does not work for me. Could you please fix the link to the feature request? I couldn't find it.

Comment: Link is updated

Comment: I did not test, but perhaps you can set a link `ln -s /dev/null ~/.mongodb/mongosh `